# .NET Compact Framework - Displaying Silverlight Websites

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-mobile, compact-framework, browser

I'm building a Windows Mobile application, based on WM 6.5 Professional SDK.

I need to display a website created with Silverlight, but standard WebBrowser Control doesn't seem to support Silverlight.

Is there any other way, to display Silverlight websites? Any other controls?

Thanks in advance for any help,
MattheW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Silverlight cannot run on Windows Mobile 6.5 and likely never will as focus moves toward [Windows Mobile 7](http://wmpoweruser.com/?p=13486).

Comment: Josh is right, if there were any way, we wouldn't have been waiting for Silverlight mobile for the past 3 years :)